# Volumetric and Deviatoric Strain Equation in 2D

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

[Strain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_%28mechanics%29) is defined as
$$\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}\left( \nabla u + \nabla u^T\right).$$

I found a formula for the strain tensor in 3D decomposed into volumetric and deviatoric components:

$$\epsilon= v + d,$$
where $v=\frac{1}{3}\epsilon_v I$ is the volumetric strain with $\epsilon_v=trace(\epsilon)$ and $d$ is the deviatoric strain.

Does this formula apply in 2D as well?  Or is $v=\epsilon_v=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_v I$ in 2D?

Comment: The answer to this question will differ if you're considering plane stress or plane strain. The best way to do these problems is to do it in 3D, then make the simplifying assumption(plane stress/strain) to 2D toward the end.

Answer (score 1):

In plane-strain, $u_3 = 0$ and $\varepsilon_{33}$ = 0. Here, 3 is the direction perpendicular to the plane of the cross-section of the body. So, $v = \varepsilon_{11} + \varepsilon_{22}$.

In plane-stress, $u_3$ is not necessarily zero and $\varepsilon_{33}$ may also be not zero everywhere. Therefore, in this case,
$v = \varepsilon_{11} + \varepsilon_{22} + \varepsilon_{33} = tr(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon})$.

In writing $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ in component form as in the above, I assumed a rectangular coordinate frame but the same holds true in cylindrical coordinate frame as well with $3$ being in the axial direction.

Answer (score 0):

The same formula does apply to 2D, 2D stress  is just a particular case of 3D stress. However sometimes you don't want to consider the 3rd dimension in 2D stress and you can work with 2D matrices and tensors and in such cases you have to replace the number 3 in your formula by the number 2